# Can't last outside a loop block

Tags: perl

I am trying to solve a problem

Rahul is playing a very interesting game. He has N disks ( each of equal radius). 
Every disk has a distinct number out of 1 to N associated with it. Disks are placed one over other in a single pile.

Rahul wants to sort this pile of disk in increasing order from top to bottom. But he has a very very special method of doing this. In a single step he can only choose one disk out of the pile and he can only put it at the top.

Rahul wants to sort his pile of disks in minimum number of possible steps. So help Rahul in doing so. So don't have to show the actual steps just answer the minimum number of possible steps to sort the pile so that that Rahul can check whether he is doing his work right or wrong.

Code  i am writing is

```
sub get_order { 
    my (@input1)= @_; 
    my @input2 = @input1;

    my $count = 0;
    sub recursive {
        my $max = 0;
        last if ( $#input2 == -1 ) ;
        foreach ( 0 .. $#input2) {
            $max = $max > $input2[$_] ? $max : $input2[$_];
            print " maximum is $max \n";
        }
        if ( $max == $input2[$max-1] ) { 
            $abc = 0;
        } else {
            $count++;
            #push @input2, $max;
        }
        # deleting that particular array index from the array
        my %hash = map { 
            $_ => "1" 
        } @input2;
        delete $hash{$max};
        print %hash;
        print "\n";
        @input2 = keys %hash;
        print "***@input2 \n";
        &recursive();
    }
    &recursive();
    print "value is $count \n"; 
    return $count;

 }

get_order(3,1,2);
```

I am getting a error Can't "last" outside a loop block at test.txt line 8.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to solve the Tower of Hanoi problem: http://hop.perl.plover.com/book/pdf/01RecursionAndCallbacks.pdf

Comment: @Zaid: I got these problems from a forum "techgig". Thought of solving this. :)

Comment: You should avoid nesting subroutines. Better to use an anonymous subroutine instead.

Comment: Great idea Slaven Rezic. But can you demonstrate little bit how to do that. Idea is looking interesting

Comment: instead of `sub recursive {` => `my $recursive = sub {` and then `$recursive->()` to call it. Btw, drop `&` in front of function calls.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Outside of `for`, `foreach`, `while`, `until`, or a naked block, you can't use `last`, `next` or `redo`

Instead you can `return` from function,

```
return if ( $#input2 == -1 ) ;
```

Comment: It's not limited to `for` and `while` - you can `last` out of a bare loop: `perl -Mstrict -wE '{ last; say "test"; }'`

Comment: @Zaid: What this means perl -Mstrict -wE '{ last; say "test"; }'

Comment: Which part don't you understand?

Comment: is this a one liner perl? I dont know one liner. What will -Mstrict do, what will -wE do and what is inside the braces

Comment: @Nitesh : It's a test demonstrating that `last` works for a bare loop. Run it in your console - it should not print `"test"` because the `last` prevents execution of subsequent statements.

Comment: `-M` is documented in perlrun. `-wE` is short for `-w -E`, documented in perlrun. Inside the brace is a `last` (which has already been covered, but also covered in perlfunc) and a `say` (which is covered in perlfunc).

Comment: @Nitesh When in doubt, `perl -h` gives quick advice.

Answer (score 4):

Part of the code is

```
sub recursive {
    my $max = 0;
    last if ( $#input2 == -1 ) ;
    foreach ( 0 .. $#input2) {
```

in these lines `last` does not occur within a `for` loop. Hence the error message.

`last` is used to exit from loop. If you want to exit from a `sub` then use `return`.

Comment: is last only for for/while loop?

Comment: All loop statements (while, iterative, foreach, C-style for and bare)